# Как задать масштаб для отображения в смартфоне?

Tags: mobile, html, css

Делаю мобильную версию сайта.
Я делаю спецстили для отображения контента в мобильных устройствах, где ширину блоков задаю `100%`, но в мобильных браузерах при первоначальной загрузке почему-то отображает слишком мелким шрифтом и никакого эффекта не получается - пользователю придется все равно приближать текст, чтобы прочитать. Вот самый простейший пример [по ссылке](http://www.spravka-azov.ru/test/test.php) - текст в моб. браузерах отображается слишком мелко, так же и во всех подобных случаях с шириной `100%`.
Как сделать так, чтобы при первоначальной загрузке страница показывалась бы в нормальном читаемом масштабе?

Comment: почему просто не увеличить шрифт для мобильных устройств?

Comment: Как это? В стилях?

Comment: Чтобы нормально читалось, приходится увеличивать аж до 48px, разве это нормально?

Answer (score 1):

Надо задавать только width=devicewidth, а масштаб не трогать. Потому что фиксированный масштаб - это жутко неудобно.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите еще и [эту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/261752/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B) тему. И про это ["простые техники адаптивной верстки"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144003/). И да, я знаю сколько прошло времени. Если есть вопрос- нужен и ответ :)